# Feature Request: Search Lists For Suggested Edits

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, tag-search

When suggested edits on your question or answer get lost in the unsearchable Recent Inbox Messages or (`user?tab=inbox`) section, how can you bring them up quickly?

Is it possible for such pending edit approvals on old posts to be picked up by something like `hasnotice:`?

Comment: Dunno for certain but they might appear under your responses->revisions: https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=responses&sort=revisions

Comment: @NickA: Bookmarked! Will be watching those, thanks.